# Is there anyway i can change the background of google meet bar to an image using a chrome extension?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I tried this and the color changed:

```
.q2u11 {
    background-color: rgb(0, 68, 255); }
```

But when i try this nothing happens:

```
.q2u11 {
    background-image: url(image1.png);
}
```

Im trying to do this using content_scripts

Comment: One thing to note, q2u11 looks like a generated css class, meaning next time they update the bundle it's likely going to change and break your edits. I'm assuming image1.png is shorthand for a hosted image somewhere online? If you check the network panel and filter for images do you see it attempting to load the image there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Add `background-image: url(imageurl);` to this `.rG0ybd.LCXT6` class using an custom chrome extension or userscript extensions like [Tamper Monkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).

Example code:

```css
.rG0ybd.LCXT6 {
  background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/random);
}
```

Working Proof:

[image]

---

#### To change `text-color` you need to select individual elements using classes.

Here are some of them

```
.Jyj1Td.CkXZgc {
  color: #e91e63; /* For "Meeting details" text */
}

.DPvwYc.o9fq9d {
  color: #ff5722; /* For present_to_all icon */
}

.YhIwSc {
  color: #27ff06; /* For "Present now" text */
}

.uJNmj.FTMc0c {
  /* For Center Buttons */
  background-color: #5907f7;
  border: 4px solid #ffc107;
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks do you also know how i can change the bottom text?

Comment: @WOLFRADIO Can you elaborate on `bottom text`?

Comment: @WOLFRADIO So you want to change text color?

Comment: yeah the text color

Comment: Let me add it to the answer 